# How to calculate $\pi(p\le0.1\,|\,=7)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, bayesian

Given priors as follows and with data $7$ successes and $43$ failures, how to calculate $\pi(p\le0.1\,|\,=7)$?

Comment: Is $y\sim \text{Binomial}(50,p)$? Are you assigning a $\text{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$ prior to $p$? Please provide more detail or your question will certainly be closed.